# Adding new field and updating field value from another shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a shapefile of route (ObjectID,Name,FirstStopID,LastStopID,length) and another shapefile of stops(ObjecID,Name,RouteName..).

I want to have the name of stops in the route shapefile, so could anyone tell me how I can add two new fields and copy the information from the stop shapefile?

All the route and stops are shapefiles exported from the Network Analyst extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you mention that data comes from a Network Analyst layer, you have to follow this workflow.

You cannot export your NA layers into shapefiles before joining the fields. This is because all the relationships between the Routes and Stops are based on `ObjectID` field, and when exporting the layers, the features may get another `ObjectID` than they have in the NA layer.

In the Routes layer, both `FirstStopID` and `LastStopID` fields values refer to the `ObjectID` of a stop in the `Stops` layer.

1. Use the Join Field GP tool for joining the input `FirstStopID` field to the Routes layer in your NA layer that is named `Route` by default.

[image]

2. Use the Join Field GP tool for joining the input `LastStopID` field to the Routes layer in your NA layer that is named `Route` by default.

[image]

3. Export your Routes layer into a shapefile or a geodatabase feature class. You will have two extra fields - `Name_1` and `Name_12` (since there was already a field Name). Feel free to rename the `Name_1` to be the `FirstStopName` and `Name_12` to be the `LastStopName`.

This is how the final dataset will look like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Alex! You gave a clear and wonderful solution!

Comment: Hi, Alex, I followed your instruction to join fields. It worked properly joining the name of first stop while it could not join the name of the last stop showing null in the attribute table. Also, there is a new field called shape_ length in the final table, which takes up the name of the first stop while the length information goes to the FirstStopName.

Comment: Bizarre. This is a bit hard to troubleshoot; I suggest starting with a really simple dataset just like the one I've used in the answer. Make sure you follow the workflow consistently.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Spatial join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000) to merge the attributes into one shapefile by the location of features. Or you could use [Join table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_joining_and_relating_tables/005s0000002n000000/) if the attributes in both shapefiles has some common fiel (like name of the route).